# optaplanner with aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

I am using optaplanner to solve a scheduling problem. I want to invoke the scheduling code from AWS Lambda (i know that Lambda's max execution time is 5 minutes and thats okay for this application)

To achieve this I have build a maven project with two modules:
module-1: scheduling optimization code
module-2: aws lambda handler ( calls scheduling code from module-1)

When i run my tests in IntelliJ Idea for module-1(that has optaplanner code), it runs fine.

When I invoke the lambda function, i get following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:    
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getInstance(ServiceRegistry.java:27)
 ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Child services [org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers] have no parent
 at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.buildMap(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:191)
 at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.getServices(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:97)
 ...
```

I have included following dependency in maven file:  org.optaplanner optaplanner-core 7.7.0.Final

Also checked that jar file have drools-core, kie-api, kei-internal, drools-compiler. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: For what's it's worth (not much), EasyScoreCalculator and IncrementalScoreCalculator won't have this problem.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet this error is happening when I initialize SolverFactory from XMLResource, much before score calculation stage.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I would expect it to happen at `solverFactory.buildSolver()`, not at `SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource()`. In the former case, the other calculators aren't affected.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet yes you are right, its happening at `solverFactory.buildSolver()`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in drools when running in a restricted environment such as AWS-lambda. Please [create a JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/DROOLS/) and link it here.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Geoffrey. I have created a jira (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-2726) ticket.

Is this something that can be fixed sooner or do you suggest any workaround?

Comment: still not fixed apparently.

Comment: I've improved bug report so it goes to the drools core guys.
**Workaround**: don't use Drools score calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error attempting to run a fat jar containing an example OptaPlanner project.  A little debugging revealed that the problem was `services` was empty when `ServiceDiscoveryImpl::buildMap` was invoked; I was using the first `META-INF/kie.conf` in the build, and as a result services were missing from that file.  Naturally your tests would work properly because the class path would contain all of the dependencies (that is, several distinct `META-INF/kie.conf` files), and not the assembly you were attempting to execute on the lambda.

Concatenating those files instead (using an appropriate merge strategy in assembly) fixes the problem and appears appropriate given how those are loaded by `ServiceDiscoveryImpl`.  The updated JAR runs properly as an AWS lambda.

Note: I was using the default `scoreDrl` from the `v7.12.0.Final` Cloud Balancing example.

Comment: Could you please give a detailed guide of what steps you did to solve this issue?

Comment: See https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.22.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_building_and_running_drools_in_a_fat_jar